# In a move constructor what means "member(other.member)"

Tags: c++, move-constructor

Probably I was not clear

```
    class Class {
    int member;
    otherClass otherClass_member;
    Class() { ... }
    Class(int x) { ... }
    Class(const Class &other) { ... }
    Class(Class &&other) : member(other.member), otherClass_member(std::move(other.otherClass_member)) {
    member=other.member;
    otherClass_member=std::move(other.otherClass_member);
    other.member=0;
    //other.otherClass_member = ???;
    }
    ~Class() { ... }
```

I have 3 questions:

1. what do this do `member(other.member), otherClass_member(std::move(other.otherClass_member))`?
2. does it need this `member=other.member; otherClass_member=std::move(other.otherClass_member);`? I'm asking that because some tutorials put and some don't.

3. if I have the code above, how should I treat this string `other.otherClass_member = ???;`

Answer (score 2):

> what do this do `member(other.member)`,
> `otherClass_member(std::move(other.otherClass_member))`?

These initialize members of the object you are constructing. Using `std::move()` allows to steal resources of the existing object `other` if `otherClass` has move constructor.

> does it need this `member=other.member;`
> `otherClass_member=std::move(other.otherClass_member);`?

Not only does not it need this, but it would be a mistake because you would be `move`ing `other.otherClass_member` twice. You could have these statements *instead of* the above initialization, but this is an inferior choice and only possible if `otherClass` has a default constructor.

> if I have the code above, how should I treat this string
> `other.otherClass_member = ???`;

You don't need it at all. Move constructor of `otherClass` should handle this (or copy constructor if move constructor does not exist).

Comment: Thank you, you were very clear and make me understand a lot of stuff in more